# codeigniter how to auto increment records from db in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, for-loop

I am trying to get 100 records at one time and then increment to next 100 and so on.For that i used limit in model but  i am getting only 100 not getting incremented can someone edit my code.

```
    $a = 0;
    for($i = $a; ; ){
        for($j = $a; ; ){
            $lim = $this->db->limit(100, $j);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $list = $query->result();
            return $list;
            if($j >= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $a = $a + 100;
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, as you have already returned the `$list` in the first loop.

Comment: i got upto 100 records but unable to increment

Comment: $j value must get incremented by 100 in each time

Comment: What type of query is this without table name how you are geeting any value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$j=0;
$count = 0;
$results = array();
do {
    $lim = $this->db->limit(100, $j);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $list = $query->result();
    array_push($results, $list);
    $count = count($list);
    $j += 100;
}
while($count == 100);
return $results;
```

Comment: still i am getting first 100 records only not getting incremented.

Comment: How are you checking the results?

Comment: i am returning the list to controller as return $list;

Comment: The list goes redefined with new entries each time loop executes. You have to push the results in an array and return the array.